# WebApi with Basic Authentication gives 500-internal error with IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

I've created a WebApi with .Net.
On localhost (Visual Studio) all works well.
Also, when I publish it on a IIS 7 on a Windows Server 2008, it works well too.

Now I want to secure some methods.
I've created as

```
public class BasicAuthHttpModule : IHttpModule
```

and in the web.config I configured this as

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="BasicAuthHttpModule" type="WebHostBasicAuth.Modules.BasicAuthHttpModule"/>
    </modules>    
</system.webServer>
```

The mehod I want to secure has [Authorize] above it.

On my localhost (debug in Visual Studio) it works well again.
With Postman I see that I can access the method with the specified username/password.

But when I put this on the IIS server, I get a 500 Internal Server Error:

> 500 – Internal server error.
>
> There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed

Must I configure IIS somewhere to achieve this, or has this an other cause?

Comment: Basic authentication is not secure unless you use HTTPS. Why cannot you use another more secure approach?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have "Basic Authentication" installed for your IIS server.

Follow the steps as to how to manage which features are installed for IIS on your server by following the steps provided here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771209.aspx

Ensure that the feature "WWW-Service" -> "Security" -> "Basic Authentication" is selected.

Alternatively, ensure that the IIS user has the required rights to the folder/files of your site. Depending on what your site does, "Read and Execute" could be enough.

The user that is used for IIS7 is IIS_IUSRS.

Additional reading on the users of IIS can be found here: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis

Comment: Unfortionally, this hasn't been the answer.
The basic authentication was already installed.
I've given the IIS_IUSRS the rights, but still the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved it!
I've discovered that there were two `<modules>` inside the `<system.webServer>` what caused the error

Comment: two inside the what?

Comment: @LCIII The syntax was removed when displaying, updated now